# Problem adding classes to DOM elements on click in IE11 and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm working on this project currently in ASP.NET MVC, and silly me have been making it and only testing it towards Chrome (Which happens to be my default browser).

There was a lot of "imperfections" once i published it to my test server, but most of those have been sorted.

I got a problem now with a button panel that expands to show some information. It works great in Chrome, and the strange thing is it works sometimes on some elements in IE11 and Edge. Also there is a difference in the look:

IE11 & Edge
[image: IE11 & Edge]
Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Chrome open
[image: Chrome open]

As you can see in the IE & Edge picture it already shows the scroll bar before the div that holds that one is shown. The second picture is how i want it to look in IE/Edge prior to click and the third picture is what it should look like after. As i said it's working in chrome.

```js
// The javascript to trigger the on click:

$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active 
class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
    padding: 0 0px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow-y: hidden
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="noPadding">
    <button class="accordion defaultSubtextHeader"><b>Show data</b></button>
    <div id="log_data" class="panel lightGreyBackground">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="flowbenchTestBox">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th class="thCenterText">Interneal Number</th>
                    <th class="thCenterText">Created</th>
                    <th class="thCenterText">Changed</th>
                    <th class="thCenterText">Minimum Battery Level</th>
                </tr>

                @if (sigfoxData != null)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">@sigfoxData.InternalNumber</td>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">@sigfoxData.Created</td>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">@sigfoxData.Changed</td>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">@sigfoxData.MinimumBatteryLevel</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:15px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css is something i found online, and i would link to the original if i could remember it but i cant.

Any idea about why it is behaving like it is? Tried adding IE11 browser fix to App_Browsers, and that sorted the other "beauty" issues.

Hope someone here can help me out. I have tried the things i could find, but nothing so far seems to be working. And this part is an issue both when running locally and on the server. The server is running .net 4.0, and i wont be able to upgrade it at this point in time.

Thanks.

Edit: Just wanted to point out that i have something between 4-6 of these on a page, and maybe 1-2 works out of them? So it might be something with the javascript being loaded before all elements have been rendered since they are staggered because they are loaded from a sql server.

Edit2: Just adding the full partial view as per comment - and dont want to mess up the runnable code example.

```
@{
var sigfoxData = ViewBag.Sigfox;
}

<h1 class="defaultHeaderFont">Sigfox</h1>
@if (sigfoxData != null)
{
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="noPadding">
        <button class="accordion defaultSubtextHeader"><b>Show data</b>    
</button>
        <div id="log_data" class="panel lightGreyBackground">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="flowbenchTestBox">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="thCenterText">Interneal Number</th>
                        <th class="thCenterText">Created</th>
                        <th class="thCenterText">Changed</th>
                        <th class="thCenterText">Minimum BatteryLevel</th>
                    </tr>

                    @if (sigfoxData != null)
                    {
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">
                            @sigfoxData.InternalNumber
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">
                            @sigfoxData.Created
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">
                            @sigfoxData.Changed
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" id="minorTextPadding">
                            @sigfoxData.MinimumBatteryLevel
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:15px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_EmptyTestView")
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted your codes into runnable snippets, however, for some reason the "Show data" does not open in the sandbox, not even in Chromium/Linux. You can check if something is missing. Original source might be https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: That indeed seems to be the example i used. And i can see that that works fin in the other browsers, which brings me back to square one pretty much.

Comment: There is a `@if (sigfoxData != null)` section in the code. This is probably the reason why it doesn't work here. You might want to hardcode this into html to have a live running reproducible example. When doing so, I suggest to remove the asp.net-mvc tag from the question.

Comment: This is part of a partial view in a Asp.net web application. Removing it here wont solve my problem since similar is done in the 4-5 other partial views. And as i also mentioned 1-2 of the panels work every time and then the other 4 wont work. Also it works in Chrome - i will add the variable sigFoxData to the code snippet as to not cause further confusion with this.

Comment: I do not think that asp.net-mvc is relevant here for solving the actual issue, thus it might increase the 'noise' in the question. [mcve]  The emphasis is on the word 'minimal' here.

Comment: I see you point. I though it might have been related to that as well. Tag has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by your JavaScript, additional HTML will be loaded dynamically. In this case you should use JQuery's event delegation `.on('event', 'selector', handlerFunc)` on an ancestor element rather than observing the DOM.

Furthermore it is alway a good idea to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, i.e. the JQuery shorthand `$(function(){})`.

Note also that you are using multiple identical IDs, however, the HTML specs say an ID has to be unique per document. I've changed that into `class`.

```js
// The javascript to trigger the on click:

$(function()
{
  $('body').on('click', 'button.accordion', function ()  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight)
    {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else
    {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active 
class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
    padding: 0 0px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow-y: hidden
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="noPadding">
  <button class="accordion defaultSubtextHeader"><b>Show data</b></button>
  <div id="log_data" class="panel lightGreyBackground">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="flowbenchTestBox">
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th class="thCenterText">Interneal Number</th>
          <th class="thCenterText">Created</th>
          <th class="thCenterText">Changed</th>
          <th class="thCenterText">Minimum Battery Level</th>
        </tr>
  
        <tr>
          <td align="center" class="minorTextPadding">Example InternalNumber</td>
          <td align="center" class="minorTextPadding">Example Created</td>
          <td align="center" class="minorTextPadding">Example Changed</td>
          <td align="center" class="minorTextPadding">Example MinimumBatteryLevel</td>
        </tr>
  
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:15px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunatly it doesn't work in my project for some reason. It doesn't even seem to fire the click event? I'm going to look in that direction and get back here if i find a solution. I'm rather new to html and css, this was a project thrown in my lap as a "nice to have". So i'll make sure to change the id's that are used multiple place to classes. Also in your example in IE and Edge it also shows the scroll bar prior to being "active". Any idea why that might be?
I'm using JQuery to call actions in the controller when the page is loaded to load the last data dunno if that matters.

Comment: Hi again! I had some more time to look at it. I managed to get your code to work with one minor exception. As mentioned i have several views loading after the page has loaded. If i put the jQuery/Javascript in the last view that is loaded it works on all of them. If i put it in the parent view it only works on the ones that are already loaded when the page loads. Any idea about how to solve this? Tried adding it to the site.js file with no luck. Problem is i don't know which view loads last as that depends on the query speed. This solution got me 95% of the way to my goal.

Comment: @JesperPurup Oops sorry, my fault. I spoke from delegation and actually uploaded the wrong code version. You have to delegate to any parent element where the dynamic inserted will apear. I've just used body. `$('body').on('click', 'button.accordion', function (){...` Answer updated, thanks for drawin my attention on it.

Comment: Thanks :D That's what i ended up doing as well. Thanks again for your help.